# Python xpath could not return list result but the first one

Tags: python, xpath

I'm using python ElementTree to scrape data from website, from console it works:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug 29 2016, 10:12:21)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib2
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> import cookielib
>>> cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
>>> opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
>>> request = urllib2.Request("http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-38551931")
>>> data = opener.open(request, timeout=4)
>>> html = data.read()
>>> tree = etree.HTML(html)
>>> r = tree.xpath("//*[@class='image-and-copyright-container']/img")
>>> r
[<Element img at 0xc6ffa0>, <Element img at 0xc7a050>, <Element img at 0xc7a0a0>, <Element img at 0xc7a0f0>, <Element img at 0xc7a140>, <Element img at 0xc7a190>, <Element img at 0xc7a1e0>, <Element img at 0xc7a230>, <Element img at 0xc7a280>]
```

But when execute in python script, it will only return the first element:

```
#coding:utf-8
import urlparse
import re
import sys
import cookielib
import urllib2
from lxml import etree

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
request = urllib2.Request("http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-china-38551841")
data = opener.open(request, timeout=4)
html = data.read()
tree = etree.HTML(html)

results = tree.xpath("//span[@class='image-and-copyright-container']/img")

for result in results:
    print "##### src:" + str(result)
```

The execution result:

```
[user@site]$ python test.py
##### src:<Element img at 0x256c230>
```

Is there anything wrong in the code or missing processing? Please help, thanks!

Comment: your xpath are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works as expected. The problem is that initial `HTML` page source of http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-38551931 already has all required images (`/span/img` elements) while initial `HTML` page source of http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-china-38551841 has only one image and other 2 elements seem to be created dynamically.

You can check this info using following scenario:

- open browser (e.g. `Firefox`)
- click `F12`
- in opened developers tools switch to `Net` (`Network`) tab
- then to `HTML` sub-tab
- navigate to http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-china-38551841 (or reload page if you've already got this `URL`)
- click on first `GET` request and switch to `Response` tab
- use `CTRL` + `F` to find entries that match `image-and-copyright-container`

As you can see there is only one `<span class="image-and-copyright-container">` with `<img>` child

To get `HTML` with all already "attached" images, you can use `Selenium` module as below:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-china-38551841")
html = driver.page_source
```

**Note** that using `selenium` might slow down your script completion

Comment: I tried your code and got an exception:      selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127

Comment: Try to download latest `chromedriver` from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.27/ or try other webdrivers, eg `Safari`, `InternetExplorer`, `Opera`... from here http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Answer (score 0):

I. Look at your xpath expressions.

1. `"//*[@class='image-and-copyright-container']/img"`
2. `"//span[@class='image-and-copyright-container']/img"`

They are different.

II. Urls are also differs.

I have used the same urls and both of you codes (even in case of different xpaths) gives the same results.